# android pause/resume video decoder implemented by MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I use below code to init a MediaCodec to decode raw H264 stream, which is streamed from a remote server.

```
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd0);
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", csd1);
    try {
        mCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create codec", e);
    }
    mCodec.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    mCodec.start();
```

And use below code to decode video byte buffer:

```
      int index = mCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (index >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                buffer = mCodec.getInputBuffers()[index];
                buffer.clear();
            } else {
                buffer = mCodec.getInputBuffer(index);
            }
            if (buffer != null) {
                buffer.put(data, offset, size);
                mCodec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, size, 0, flags);
            }
        }
```

I need to add pause resume when screen turn off. I got a exception when turn off screen:

```
02-12 10:40:59.249 17398 17450 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException
02-12 10:40:59.249 17398 17450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
02-12 10:40:59.249 17398 17450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2726)
```

What's proper way to pause/resume MediaCodec?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not in the `MediaCodec` but in the `Surface` that you used to configure it with. A `Surface` is an interface for a producer (e.g. `MediaCodec`) to exchange buffers with a consumer.

If the `Surface` comes from a [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) or [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView) then you should be aware of its lifecycle. The `Surface` is created and destroyed as the view's window is shown and hidden.

After the `Surface` has been destroyed the buffers will not be available anymore. You should implement the relevant callbacks (e.g. `surfaceCreated`, `surfaceDestroyed`) for managing the workflow.

One option is to release the codec when the surface is destroyed and create a new one when the surface is created. Or you could reuse the same codec instance by stopping it when the surface is destroyed and configuring it using a new surface when the latter is created.

In both cases don't forget to make sure that the first buffer that you feed into the decoder is an I-frame.

More about `MediaCodec` [states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#states).